# On Firefox of Android, google one-tap prompt displays on right corner instead of on bottom

Tags: javascript, android, firefox

Recently, I add google one-tap to our web. it works fine on chrome of Android, chrome, and firefox of IOS. But it displays on the right corner on the firefox of Android instead of on the bottom. Obviously, google one-tap library can't detect the browser is on mobile. Is there any solution to fix this?

Comment: firefox version - 68.4.1

Comment: android version 8.0.0

Answer (score 0):

This should be already fixed on Google side. Please verify.